# OpenCasCade BrepFeat_MakeCylindricalHole(); function

Tags: c++, opencascade

Currently I'm working on a project to drill some cylindrical holes on to a given shape.

So for do that I did use `BRepFeat_MakeCylindricalHole();` function and used `Standard_EXPORT void PerformThruNext (const Standard_Real Radius, const Standard_Boolean WithControl = Standard_True);`

Because in this scenario I haven't the depth of the cylinder. Using performThruNext it will drilled, Top face to Bottom face.
User will be given the start and the end points, then using that will be drilling holes.

1. **1.when start and end points having decimal fraction part `(gp_pnt StartPnt (328.547,-4.325,97.412);
   gp_pnt EndPnt
   (291.841,-7.586,101.651);)`, it doesn't drill the face correctly.

2.when diameter getting to a higher value,happens the same thing,
,

** following is my code,any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

```
void COCCAPPDoc::OnBox2()
{

ofstream out;
out.open("C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/Blade/areaInit.txt");
CString str;

TopoDS_Shape bladeWithCore,DrilledShape,DrilledShape2;

/* IMPORT bladeWithCore.brep FILE */
Standard_CString strFile = "C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/Blade/bladeWithCore.brep";
BRep_Builder brepS;
BRepTools::Read(bladeWithCore,strFile,brepS);

TopoDS_Face Face_52;
Standard_CString strFace = "C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/Blade/Face_52.brep";
BRep_Builder brepF;
BRepTools::Read(Face_52,strFace,brepF);

BRepClass3d_SolidClassifier classify;
classify.Load(bladeWithCore);
classify.PerformInfinitePoint(1.0e-6);
TopAbs_State state = classify.State();
if(state==TopAbs_IN) bladeWithCore.Reverse();

DrilledShape = bladeWithCore;

gp_Vec v1(gp_Pnt( 330,11,108),gp_Pnt(291,4,109)); //FINDING VECTOR FROM START TO THE END POINT
gp_Pnt point(330,11,108);

gp_Pnt startpoint (330,11,108);
TopoDS_Vertex aV1 = BRepBuilderAPI_MakeVertex (startpoint);
BRepTools::Write(aV1,"C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/Blade/startpoint.brep");

/* gp_Vec v1(gp_Pnt( 330.208114,11.203318,108.480255),gp_Pnt(291.103558,4.265285,109.432663));
gp_Pnt point(330.208114,11.203318,108.480255);*/

gp_Dir d1(v1); //GETTING DIRECTION USING FOUND VECTOR
gp_Vec UnitVector(d1); //FINDING UNITVECTOR

gp_Dir dir_line(0,0,1);
gp_Vec UnitVector_line(dir_line);

gp_Pnt minPoint;
Standard_Real diameter = 0.1;

int noOfInstances =3;
int gap = -10;

for(int i=0; i {

point.Translate(UnitVector);

gp_Pnt newPoint = point;
newPoint.Translate(UnitVector_line*10);
BRepBuilderAPI_MakeEdge LINE(newPoint, point);
BRepBuilderAPI_MakeWire lineWire(LINE);

TopoDS_Wire wire = TopoDS::Wire(lineWire);
TopoDS_Shape lineShape = TopoDS_Shape(wire);
BRepTools::Write(lineShape,"C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/Blade/linlineShapee.brep");

intersection( bladeWithCore,lineShape, point, minPoint);

TopoDS_Vertex checkPoint = BRepBuilderAPI_MakeVertex (minPoint);
BRepTools::Write(checkPoint,"C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/Blade/checkPoint.brep");

gp_Ax1 location =gp_Ax1(minPoint,gp_Dir(0,0,1));
BRepFeat_MakeCylindricalHole drilled;
drilled.Init(DrilledShape,location);
drilled.PerformThruNext(diameter/2.0);

BRepFeat_Status status = drilled.Status();

if(status==BRepFeat_NoError)
{
DrilledShape = drilled.Shape();
BRepTools::Write(DrilledShape,"C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/Blade/bladeWithCoreDrilled.brep");
}

}
Handle(AIS_InteractiveObject) obj3 = (new AIS_Shape(DrilledShape));
myAISContext->Display(obj3);
COCCAPPDoc:: Fit();
}

void COCCAPPDoc::intersection(TopoDS_Shape bladeWithCore,TopoDS_Shape lineShape,gp_Pnt point,gp_Pnt& minPoint)
{

BRepExtrema_DistShapeShape  interSection( bladeWithCore, lineShape, Extrema_ExtFlag_MIN, Extrema_ExtAlgo_Grad);
interSection.Perform();
Standard_Integer Solutions = interSection.NbSolution();

CArray disArray;
int minindex = 1;

for(int i = 1; i {

double distance = point.Distance((interSection.PointOnShape1(i)));
disArray.Add(distance);

}

for(int i = 1; i {

if(disArray[0] > disArray[i])
{
disArray[0] = disArray[i];
minindex = i;

}
}
minPoint = interSection.PointOnShape1(minindex);
TopoDS_Vertex aV = BRepBuilderAPI_MakeVertex (minPoint);
BRepTools::Write(aV,"C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/Blade/minPoint.brep");
}
```

Comment: Would be nice if you could provide a few more information.... for example, where exactly is it failing? Is it really the PerformThruNext method that is failing?  If so, what is the BRepFeat_Status in the case of error?

Comment: when my cylindrical hole placed between edges of the 2 faces, Boolean cut operation will be failed. I figured out it is not some thing with the decimal fraction values, when the cut operation happens, if my cylinder placed in 2 faces that it is failing.

Comment: when my cylindrical hole placed between edges of the 2 faces, Boolean cut operation will be failed. I figured out it is not some thing with the decimal fraction values, when the cut operation happens, if my cylinder placed in 2 faces that it is failing.